# Conditional navigation on tap of notification ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I want to navigate specific screen when i will tap on notification, i  tried to do this but not able to decide the approach. So any one ca guide me how to do this.

I tried by deciding to put json string for "alert" key but when app is closed that json is displaying as it is.

Depend on text in notification i have to decide the which screen needs to be displayed. also have read some private id. which should not be displayed in notification.

Answer (score 1):

Your server, who sends you push notifications, must include some field in the payload which you must read when a user opens the app and show a screen based on that field's value.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //...
    NSDictionary *pushUserInfo = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
    if (pushUserInfo) {
        [self handlePushNotificationWithUserInfo:pushUserInfo];
    }
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [self handlePushNotificationWithUserInfo:userInfo];
}

- (void)handlePushNotificationWithUserInfo:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        return;
    }

    id someValue = userInfo[@"someField"]; 
    if (someValue == ...) {
       //Open screen
    } else if (someValue == ...) {
       //Open another screen
    } // and so on
}
```

Comment: i dont want to show this "someField" in notification when app is closed

Comment: i created following json 
{
"notificationType" : "General",
"notificationTitle" : "Now Available - Push Notifications for Network Analyst (INA) Threshold Alarms",
"notificationMessage" : "To manage notifications, log in to the mobile app and choose settings."
}
this string gets displayed as it is if app if closed

Comment: Yes!
In the notification will be shown only "alert" message. Other field are invisible for the user.